# When and where to Initialize Custom membership provider

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

As our application is an existing one and with lots of data we decided to implement our own MembershipProvider.

In this process I had to customize CreateUser with different signature. And this is my signature.

```
public MembershipUser CreateUser(string firstName, string lastName, string password, string email, string phone, out MembershipCreateStatus status, string title = null, UserRole role = UserRole.User)
    {
        // New user logic
    }
```

I am calling this CeateUser method after initializing my provider. As I am initializing the instance, but I am not calling the Initialize method on that instance. How to avoid this initialization part and calling my CreateUser method.

```
var provider = new EastpointMembershipProvider(); 

            provider.CreateUser(model.UserName,string.Empty,  model.Password, model.Email, string.Empty,out createStatus,"Mr");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After browsing for a while I found no need to Initialize the custom membership provider explicitly.

Initialize will be called when we retrieve provider from Membership.Provders["ProviderName"].

```
var membership = (CustomMembershipProvider)Membership.Providers["CustomMembershipProvider"];
```

Comment: you're my savior  I did like this: FNHMembershipProvider membershipProvider = (FNHMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider;